# Benefits of maven default filters directory

Tags: java, maven

Recently I have discovered maven resource filtering and saw one note in documentation:

> **Standard Directory Layout**
>   src/main/filters  Resource filter files

I have noticed that maven does not search files declared in `<filter>` tag in this directory by default. So what are the benefits of sticking with Maven Layout in this case (except structure uniformity ofcourse)?

Comment: Structure uniformity is the benefit. This question is really opinion-based.

Answer (score 6):

The `src/main/filters` directory contains the [filters](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html#filters) not the files to be filtered. Maven cannot search filters automatically, because it could not know which filters to use.

See [Maven: The Complete Reference](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/lifecycle-sect-common-goals.html):

> **default.properties in src/main/filters.**
>
> ```
> jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:mydb
> jdbc.username=sa
> jdbc.password=
> ```
>
> To configure resource filtering with this *default.properties* file, we need to specify two things in a project’s POM: a list of properties files in the `filters` element of the build configuration, and a flag to Maven that the resources directory is to be filtered. The default Maven behavior is to skip filtering and just copy the resources to the output directory; you’ll need to explicitly configure resource filter, or Maven will skip the step altogether. This default ensures that Maven’s resource filtering feature doesn’t surprise you out of nowhere and clobbering any *${...}* references you didn’t want it to replace.
>
> **Filter Resources (Replacing Properties).**
>
> ```
> <build>
>     <filters>
>         <filter>src/main/filters/default.properties</filter>
>     </filters>
>     <resources>
>         <resource>
>             <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
>             <filtering>true</filtering>
>         </resource>
>     </resources>
> </build>
> ```

Answer (score 6):

Basically you're assuming that the files that are present in *src/main/filters* (or *src/test/filters*) are themselves filterable. That assumption isn't correct.

The purpose of the *src/main/filters* folder is to contain the resource filter files that will be used by Maven during the filtering action.

For instance, imagine that you have the following property defined:

```
<project>
...
<properties>
    <my.property>foo</my.property>
</properties>
...
</project>
```

And now imagine that you're filtering some folder:

```
...
<resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
</resource>
...
```

With that definition, any file inside *src/main/resources* that contains *${my.property}* will be replaced by *foo*.

Now imagine that you don't want to change your POM every time you want to add a new property.

Then is when *src/main/filters* comes into action. Instead of placing your properties in your POM, you create a file under *src/main/filters* with your properties and you add a filter to your POM:

```
<project>
    ...
    <name>Some Project</name>
    ...
    <build>
        ...
        <filters>
            <filter>my-filter.properties</filter>
        </filters>
        ...
    </build>
    ...
</project>
```

Comment: @user3177112, but it does look to that directory first. In fact, besides the *properties* tag on the POMs, that's the only other place where you can place properties that will be used during the resource filtering process.

Answer (score 1):

The main benefit is that when someone goes looking for filters, they look in `src/main/filters`, and if they don't see a `src/main/filters` they often quickly assume you don't have any filters.

As someone else also mentioned, you only put the filters in `src/main/filters` it is not a place where you put things that need to be filtered.

Comment: >it is not a place where you put things that need to be filtered |
I know, that, what thing in my post made you think otherwise?

Comment: @user3177112 Sometimes we put information in that clarifies things you don't personally need clarified; mostly because there is someone else out there on the Internet that probably needs the clarification.  I hope you didn't take offense; but I clarified it because I have helped others who were confused on this point.

Comment: No offense at all, I appreciate your will to help me, just 3 simillaly mislead posters made me think about it :)