# Override Maven default filter directory

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

Is it possible to override Maven default filters directory

```
${project.basedir}/src/main/filters
```

to e.g.

```
${project.basedir}/filters
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/35989386/7094618

Comment: It doesn't answer my question. Let's say I add `<filter>someFilter.properties</filter>` in the list of filters. Then maven will try to find it in `${project.basedir}/src/main/filters`. How can Maven be forced to look for it in `${project.basedir}/filters` instead.

Comment: First why would you like to ignore the conventions? What are the reasons? Can you show the pom file you are using?